# Codeigniter and Hack Language

Tags: php, hhvm, hacklang

I am wondering  how and if it is possible to run Hack code with HHVM in codeigniter models and controllers.

Also are there any active efforts to port PHP frameworks like CI into Hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering how and if it is possible to run Hack code with HHVM in codeigniter models and controllers.

Yep! Hack has full backwards compatibility with PHP. You should start by making sure that CodeIgniter runs on HHVM. [100% of its unit tests are passing on HHVM](http://www.hhvm.com/frameworks/), so I expect that you'll have very good luck with this.

Then, you can just start writing Hack code right alongside CodeIgniter. HHVM will allow Hack to call into PHP and PHP to call into Hack with no problems. [The Hack type system](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/install.hack.bootstrapping.php) won't know anything about the PHP code, so it won't be able to help you with type errors at the boundary, but everything will work.

> Also are there any active efforts to port PHP frameworks like CI into Hack?

I'm not aware of any right now. Contrary to what the other answer said, this would definitely be a useful thing to do though! Even if CI didn't want to take advantage of [the many benefits of the Hack language](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hacklangref.php), if they even wanted to add type annotations, that would definitely help anyone who wanted to use CI with Hack! So converting an existing project to Hack has definite benefits for users, and then you can continue to gradually use more of the features of Hack.

The major problem is that Hack only runs on HHVM; existing users of CI wouldn't be able to use the PHP5 engine. The Hack team has a solution for this we're going to announce very soon, stay tuned :)

Comment: josh, thanks!  privilege  to have a question answered by a core member. Keep up the good work guys!

Answer (score 1):

**I am wondering how and if it is possible to run Hack code with HHVM in codeigniter models and controllers.**

Hack code will run anywhere that PHP does - all it requires is changing `<?php` tags to `<?hh` (which is a 'find and replace' you can actually do without it cocking everything up!!!!)

However you do need to have the [**H**ip**H**op **V**irtual **M**achine(**HHVM**)](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm) running on your server.

**Also are there any active efforts to port PHP frameworks like CI into Hack?**

NO - and it would be pointless - HHVM is designed to run PHP (literally, it was designed for PHP compilation to bytecode), Hack is just an extension of the PHP language (not quite but simplest explanation)

The Good News?????? - you can just drop CI straight onto your server and run it through HHVM and you will get the speed benefits of a Just In Time compiler!!!!! [It Works straight out of the box](http://hhvm.com/frameworks/) (apparently - haven't tried it, but tried Laravel and it works great with very little adjustment!)

I think you misunderstood what Hack and HHVM actually are so hopefully the above clarifies a little.

**IN SUMMARY**

HHVM is a virtual machine service that runs on your server, that changes PHP from a dynamic language to a compiled (Just-In-Time) language, making it a LOT faster (I mean, stupidly fast)

Hack is a language that runs on HHVM and will play very nicely with PHP - think of it as an extension of PHP, not a replacement.

Anything written in PHP can be extended / written from TODAY in Hack.

You COULD rewrite some parts of PHP to take advantage of some of the 'extras' Hack gives you, but seems to me to be 'over-optimisation'.

Hope that helps and is clear.